# How to use media3 (with Exoplayer + MediaSessionService)

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

How to implement MediaSessionService and build a very simple audioplayback app with media3? I tried it, but unsuccessfully. I also couldn't find a simple documentation...

Answer (score 8):

The library suffers lack of documentation (as will probably be the case until a stable release).

For a simple implementation for audio playback, which also supports background playback, we need to have our player separated from our activity, and rather live in something isolated from it but can still be part of our application, the answer is a `Service`, and services can use application context freely, and can run in the background.

So let's assume you want to create an app that plays music, you will need:

- An activity (let's call it `MainActivity`)
- A service (let's call it `MusicPlayerService`)

***1- First of all,*** we declare our activity in the manifest (I believe everyone is familiar with this step).

***2- Second of all,*** we declare our service in the manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name=".MusicPlayerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaLibraryService"/>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

***3- Now for the important steps,*** we build the necessary architecture for our Media3 library. The UI (MainActivity) has something called 'MediaController' which is basically an interface with the player that lives in the service.

As for the service, there is something called a MediaSession that lives inside it, and also the player itself (exoplayer). There is a special version of media session which controls also the media items (playlist and its info) and exposes it to other clients (such Android Auto, WearOS, etc). It's called MediaLibraryService, we're gonna be experimenting with this one today (but the process of implementation is almost the same).

So, in our MainActivity:

```kotlin
@UnstableApi class MusicActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    /* This is the global variable of the player
       (which is basically a media controller) 
       you're going to use to control playback,
       you're not gonna need anything else other than this,
       which is created from the media controller */
    lateinit var player: Player

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        /* Creating session token (links our UI with service and starts it) */
        val sessionToken = SessionToken(applicationContext, ComponentName(this, MusicPlayerService::class.java))

        /* Instantiating our MediaController and linking it to the service using the session token */
        val mediacontrollerFuture = MediaController.Builder(this, sessionToken).buildAsync()

        mediacontrollerFuture.addListener({


            player = mediacontrollerFuture.get()


        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
    }
}
```

***Now for the most interesting part,*** we create a class called `MusicPlayerService` which extends `MediaLibraryService` (or MediaSessionService, depends on your app needs), it is like this:

```kotlin
@UnstableApi class MusicPlayerService: MediaLibraryService() {

    /* This is the service side player, the media controller in the activity will control this one, so don't worry about it */
    lateinit var player: Player

    /* This is the session which will delegate everything you need about audio playback such as notifications, pausing player, resuming player, listening to states, etc */
    lateinit var session: MediaLibrarySession
    
    override fun  onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        
        /* Step 1 out of 2: Instantiate the player (ExoPlayer) */
        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(applicationContext)
            .setRenderersFactory(
                DefaultRenderersFactory(this).setExtensionRendererMode(
                    DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER /* We prefer extensions, such as FFmpeg */
                )
            ).build()


        /* Step 2 out of 2: Instantiate the session (most important part) */
        session = MediaLibrarySession.Builder(this, player,
            object: MediaLibrarySession.Callback {
                override fun onAddMediaItems(
                    mediaSession: MediaSession,
                    controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo,
                    mediaItems: MutableList<MediaItem>
                ): ListenableFuture<MutableList<MediaItem>> {

                /* This is the trickiest part, if you don't do this here, nothing will play */
                    val updatedMediaItems = mediaItems.map { it.buildUpon().setUri(it.mediaId).build() }.toMutableList()
                    return Futures.immediateFuture(updatedMediaItems)
                }
            }).build()
    }
}
```

***One last thing***, if you want to load a media item in an activity, use this:

```kotlin
fun loadMediaItem(uri: Uri) {
    /* We use setMediaId as a unique identifier for the media (which is needed for mediasession and we do NOT use setUri because we're gonna do
       something like setUri(mediaItem.mediaId) when we need to load the media like we did above in the MusicPlayerService and more precisely when we were building the session */
    val newItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setMediaId("$uri") /* setMediaId and NOT setUri */
        .build()
    
    /* Load it into our activity's MediaController */
    player.setMediaItem(newItem)
    player.prepare()
    player.play()
}
```

Hope this gives you a better approach on Media3.

Comment: info is already available with Media3 https://developer.android.com/media/implement/playback-app

Comment: @user924 Correct. At the time of writing my answer, documentation didn't exist. The library is well-documented as of now.

Comment: yeah, but just in case someone will get here as well )