# How to add Exo Player to Android Notification Status bar when the player is playing

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I have a MediaPlayerActivity.kt

```
package com.media.apps

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import tz.co.smartcodes.mpaper.R
import tz.co.smartcodes.mpaper.services.MediaPlayerService

class MediaPlayerHelper : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var isMediaPlaying = false
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.audio_player)

        val playButton = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.btnPause)
        val pauseButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btnVolume)

        if (!isMediaPlaying) {
            val mediaUrl = MEDIA_URL

            val intent = Intent(this@MediaPlayerHelper, MediaPlayerService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("media_url", mediaUrl)
            startService(intent)
            isMediaPlaying = true
            playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_pause_circle_48)
        }

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (isMediaPlaying) {
                val intent = Intent(this@MediaPlayerHelper, MediaPlayerService::class.java)
                stopService(intent)
                isMediaPlaying = true
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val MEDIA_URL =
            "https://mpaper.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stories/story_118_90207270-2aca-11ee-806a-757cf48e4d1c.mp3"
    }
}
```

I have a MediaPlayerService.kt with the following code

```
package com.media.apps

import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.media3.common.MediaItem
import androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaSource
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector


class MediaPlayerService : Service() {

    private var player: ExoPlayer? = null

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        val mediaUrl = intent?.getStringExtra("media_url")
        if (mediaUrl != null) {
            playerMedia(mediaUrl)
        }
        return START_STICKY
    }


    private fun playerMedia(mediaUrl: String) {
        releasePlayer()
        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setTrackSelector(DefaultTrackSelector(this))
            .build()
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(mediaUrl)
        val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
            DefaultDataSource.Factory(this)
        ).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
        player?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        player?.prepare()
        player?.playWhenReady = true
    }

    private fun releasePlayer() {
        player?.release()
        player = null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        releasePlayer()
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml
 `<service android:name=".services.MediaPlayerService"/>`

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white_black"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/storyName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/size_20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_4"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/black_white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/channelName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/size_20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_12"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/rifary_input"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnBackward"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_4"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txtSongTime"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtStartTime"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/size_4"
        android:theme="@style/Progress_color" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/size_20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStartTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0 : 0 " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSongTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnForward"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="0 : 0  " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/size_12"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnVolume"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_volume_up" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnBackward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow___left_circle"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/size_8" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/size_16">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btnPause"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/baseline_play_circle_48"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/play_now" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/spinner_loader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <ProgressBar
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminateTint="@color/rifaly_green"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnForward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@+id/imageButton3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow___right_circle"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/size_8"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@+id/imageButton3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I tried so far is to add a foreground function that create a notification manager with play, pause and close is called in onStartCommand I have removed it since it is not working

The player works fine it opens an audio. I can't find a way to implement this thing any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use MediaSessionService to implement that, and you can find a simple example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560520/how-to-use-media3-with-exoplayer-mediasessionservice)

Refs:

[MediaSessionSerive](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/session/mediasessionservice)

[MediaSession](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/session/mediasession)